# Printing Array Braces in Excel

Tags: excel, printing, formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with array formulas.  I can see the formulas with the braces in the formula bar, but when I display the formulas using "Show Formulas", the braces do not display.  Is there a way to obtain print output with the array braces?

It displays in formula bar like this:

```
{=C3:C7*D3:D7}
```

When it is displayed in the cell using 'show formulas', it displays like this:

```
=C3:C7*D3:D7
```

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 1):

After I read it again after the edits it makes more sense what you are trying to do. I am not sure if you can print it with the braces it looks like only the formula bar displays the braces and not the cell. When you try to edit the formula bar the braces disappear. I was trying to find the value that holds this information of the formula with "{" included and so far have not found it.

I tried to get the information from the command bar and it doesn't appear that it is there.

example:

```
  msgbox(Application.CommandBars("Formula Bar").Tag)
```

This is a very good question and it doesn't appear that the information is made available in the VBA objects. Does anyone else know if there is an object that would hold this information?

Thanks,
Clint

Comment: yes, Control+` only prints out the formula without the braces.  We are using Excel 2010.  Thank you David for helping with the entry.  I am new at this.